# Laravel: How do I autofocus an input field when there is/isn't an error in the var $error?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-form

If there is an error in a particular input, I want to highlight it and focus it, and it works as expected.

However, if there are no errors (default case), the first input should focus, which it doesn't. How do I add these two options to the array? Take a look at the first form group.

```
<div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('name') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
    {{ Form::text('name', null, [
        (!$errors) ? 'autofocus' : '',        // if no errors, autofocus because default
        ($errors->has('name')) ? 'autofocus' : ''   // if error in name, autofocus
    ]) }}
</div>

<div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
    {{ Form::email('email', null, [
        ($errors->has('email')) ? 'autofocus' : ''   // if error in email, autofocus
    ]) }}
</div>

<div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
    {{ Form::password('password', [
        ($errors->has('password')) ? 'autofocus' : ''   // if error in password, autofocus
    ]) }}
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
....
'autofocus' => $errors->has('password') ? 'autofocus' : null,
....
```

Comment: I did this for all: 'autofocus' => (!$errors) ? 'autofocus' : '';
        'autofocus' => ($errors->has('name')) ? 'autofocus' : '';
        'autofocus' => ($errors->has('email')) ? 'autofocus' : '';
        'autofocus' => ($errors->has('password')) ? 'autofocus' : '';

Now with or without the error, only the name field is being autofocused.

Comment: try $errors->first('email') like this for all